# How to test file uploads in a REST API using Azure Load Test and JMeter

Tags: azure, rest, jmeter, load-testing

I'm writing up a series of load tests in JMeter, one of which tests a REST API endpoint that POSTs a form file:

```
[HttpPost("File")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

I can do this with JMeter through the File Upload tab of the HTTP Request Sampler:

[image: JMeter snapshot]

This works fine, but since `C:/my-file.txt` is on my local machine, once I upload the .JMX file to Azure Load Test, the file reference becomes invalid, and the tests all fail with an internal `File Not Found` exception.

I've experimented with both JMeter and Azure, but have had no luck finding a way to provide a file for upload once my load test is imported into Azure. Is this just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `C:\` from the file path and upload the `file.txt` along with your test like it's done with [CSV files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-read-csv-data?tabs=portal) or [JMeter Plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-jmeter-plugins?tabs=portal)

If Azure doesn't support feeding data files in this way you can i.e. encode the file contents into Base64 and set it as [secret or environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-parameterize-load-tests). The file can be created from the secret or the environment variable in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) with the help of [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. I updated the file reference in JMeter to be just the filename, then uploaded that file to the Test Plan tab when creating the test in Azure (I didn't realise it accepted more than just .jmx files). Those 2 changes were all I needed.